# Crear script sh que simule cambio de ventana con screen y pulsaciones de teclas con xdotool

Tags: screen, sh

Me encuentro en la necesidad de generar un script sh para ejecutar una serie de comandos en en VPS con intercambio de ventanas screen incluído.

El script debe realizar lo siguiente.

```
1) cambiar a una ventana concreta de screen  
2) pulsar control + c para cerrar la aplicación que está trabajando 
3) ejecutar de nuevo la aplicación
```

Con todo esto he sacado el script tal que así

```
sudo screen -r -D windowName
sleep 3
sudo xdotool key ctrl+c
./appName
```

Pero cuando llega a la ventana de screen ya no ejecuta el control+c
Imagino que el control +c se ejecuta en la ventana screen donde se ha iniciado todo, pero no sabría como "trasladar" esa ejecución a la nueva ventana screen 
Alguna idea?

Comment: Puedes usar este Post. https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/find-window-by-its-name-and-activate-it-bring-to-foreground/. usando la funcion windowactivate

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que la señal de interrupción `SIGINT` debe ser enviada como un comando y no ingresar a la sesión mediante la opción de `reattach`. Para ésto usaría la opción `-X` de la siguiente forma

```sh
$ sudo screen -S TestScreen -X stuff $'\003'
```

Faltaría el relanzamiento de la aplicación. Conociendo la ruta ejecutaría

```sh
$ sudo screen -S TestScreen -X stuff '/home/usuario/appName
> '
```

Observe bien que se envía `'` como segundo comando.

Comment: Gracias Johann. Le voy a echar un vistazo aunque la respuesta que me dejaron como comentario es la que realmente me ha servido para terminar el script como quería.